# store/fetch data from a big ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm building an application that is connected to an API that returns lots of lists with the same model and with lots of views that might duplicate that model ,

so i figure instead of storing multi lists that need to notify other lists about changes in the model , I can have 1 list that gets updated with changes and fetch data from .
in a way I made a small database with one table that will stay in the RAM

My first question is that gonna be a memory issue if the list gets big ? (currently i maxed it to 700 items with no problem at the user's end)

Secondly the way i'm fetching data is looping in that list constantly and filtering as needed ,is that gonna effect performance when list gets big too ?

And lastly is't this structure faster than a Sqllite database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is faster to access elements from the `ArrayList` where the time is O(1). But it will be significally slower to filter the List by iterating over it. This will lead to O(N) and even more worse if you need to compare the elements inside the list which will lead to O(N^2) and so on.

So if you plan on quick access only then keeping it in the memory is fine, but if you need to do some sql queries on it then you should opt for a datastore solution. Either the in-built SQLite store or something like Realm.

Answer (score 1):

> is that gonna be a memory issue if the list gets big ? (currently i maxed it to 700 items with no problem at the user's end)

This is not an issue as long as you are only reading data from that list no, especially with the newer phones nowadays.

> is that gonna effect performance when list gets big too ?

This is going to be an issue to you, iterating over 700 items won't be an issue but if you start dealing with bigger numbers 5 or 6 digits items it will start to be an issue.

But all of this depends on your items so if your items in the list is only text then i would say you can keep on the same way. But if your list start having images, bigger texts or more data then you should consider saving this data in a database and then process it.